# udp broadcast on port 25860

Tags: wireshark, udp, packet-capture

I used wireshark on my local network (to test it), and i noticed that there is a lot of udp packets send one broadcast, and the majority is coming from only one host. Theses udp packets are send on broadcast on the port 25860.

Seing all theses packets sent to the same port, and always have the same data, i thought that it might be a known packet (such as DNS request may be or something like that). So, can someone tell me what is the purpose of theses packets (if they have one) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not one of the "standard" ports (e.g. for FTP, SIP, SNMP, etc...) so it's probably some proprietary protocol, but it's impossible to tell for sure with so little information.

I would suggest you run netstat -a -b on the host (assuming it's Windows and that you have admin rights on it) to determine what process is using that port.